# Есть ли способ по результату выполнения транзакции сделать коммит или отменить изменения mysql

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, transaction

Уважаемые знатоки. Возникла такая проблема:
Мне необходимо выполнить две хранимые процедуры друг за другом, и если хотя бы одна из них прошла неудачно, отменить всю транзакцию.

```
START TRANSACTION;
   trans_1(1, 1, @i1); #этот запрос сможет выполниться и в @i1 попадет число > 0
   trans_1(12, 1, @i2); #этот запрос не сможет выполниться и в @i2 попадет -1
   IF @i1 < 1 OR @i2 < 1 THEN ROLLBACK;
   ELSE COMMIT;
```

Хотелось бы что-то вроде такого, но этот вариант не работает, я написал его просто для демонстрации желаемого.
СУБД PHPMyAdminV5.0.2
MySQL v8.0
Буду рад вашим примерам и объяснениям.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: *необходимо выполнить две транзакции друг за другом, и если хотя бы одна из них прошла неудачно, отменить всю транзакцию.* Бред сивой кобылы. Если транзакция зафиксирована - то она зафиксирована. И её невозможно откатить (восстановление из бэкапа не рассматриваем). Это я про первую из двух транзакций.

Comment: Мой косяк. Две хранимые процедуры в рамках одной транзакции.

Comment: А тогда какие проблемы? Проверь, что внутри процедур нет никаких запросов, вызывающих неявный коммит, и если их нет - просто оборачивай вызов этих процедур в транзакцию, и обеспечь передачу из процедур флага успешности процедуры (или используй один флаг - пользовательскую переменную), устанавливая его значение в EXIT HANDLER. А по завершении процедур на основании значения флага либо фиксируй, либо откатывай.

Comment: Вот в это то и проблема, что я передаю наружу влаг, но не понимаю, как на основании его значения что-то сделать. Я пытался написать условие, но блок if then не работает вне функции. Можно пример, как это должно выглядеть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну... схематично, при использовании UDV в качестве флага, где-то так:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1 (...)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    SET @flag = FALSE;
-- действия процедуры 1
END;
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE proc2 (...)
BEGIN
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
    SET @flag = FALSE;
-- действия процедуры 2
END
```

```sql
START TRANSACTION;
SET @flag = TRUE;
CALL proc1(...);
IF @flag THEN
    CALL proc2(...);
END IF;
IF @flag THEN
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

Comment: Подогнал запрос под себя
```
DELIMITER /
CREATE PROCEDURE proc1(IN tab VARCHAR)
BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION;
    SET @flag = FALSE;
    SELECT * FROM tab;
END;/

CREATE PROCEDURE proc2(IN tab VARCHAR)
BEGIN
 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION;
    SET @flag = FALSE;
    SELECT * FROM tab;
END;/
DELIMITER ;
START TRANSACTION;
SET @flag = TRUE;
CALL proc1();
IF @flag THEN
    CALL proc2();
END IF;
IF @flag THEN
    COMMIT;
ELSE
    ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```
Выдает ошибку синтаксиса №1064 на строке BEGIN

Comment: @Андрей Да, действительно, имеется ошибка синтаксиса. И далеко не одна. Напоминаю - я показываю схематично, а не даю готовый код. Впрочем, даже в то, что я показал, ты умудрился добавить синтаксических ошибок.

Comment: Что поделать, я в sql новичек. Вдобавок, даже код с оф. сайта у меня почему-то содержит синтаксические ошибки. Может дело в СУБД, может в том, что я криворукий, может в типе бд. В любом случае, у меня не работает. За ответ спасибо. Но, может кто-то даст пример рабочего кода.

Comment: Дело в том, что Вы в синтаксисе плаваете, но в документацию упорно не смотрите. Зачем надо было влеплять точку с запятой между декларацией хандлера и его телом, а? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare-handler.html А третий блок кода, который обращается к хранимым процедурам, использует условные операторы, которые могут применяться только и исключительно в compound statement - а Вы небось их просто пытаетесь выполнить в пакетном режиме. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html

Comment: Я кое что понял. Моя СУБД отмечала запросы из документации как некорректные, потому я считал их таковыми, однако, они все-таки исполняются. С другой стороны, запросы, которые СУБД считает корректными на деле таковыми не являются. Видимо, дело в СУБД. В любом случае, спасибо за помощь, я еще поразбираюсь и, думаю, найду решение.